# JSON request formatting issue

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, sap-commerce-cloud

I wrote one request DTO using beans.xml, I used @JsonPropertyOrder and @JsonProperty annotation as follow in beans.xml :

```
<bean ...>
 <annotations>@JsonPropertyOrder({
            "FirstName",
            "LastName"
        })
        <property name="FirstName" type="java.lang.String" >
            <annotations>@JsonProperty("FirstName")</annotations>
        </property>
        <property name="LastName" type="java.lang.String" >
            <annotations>@JsonProperty("LastName")</annotations>
        </property>
</bean>
```

Also I used the ObjectMapper to convert DTO object to Json string. 
But when actually json sent to third party I observed:

1. although I used @JsonPropertyOrder , order of elements is different then what it is written.
2. In request string FirstName and LastName is coming as **firstName** , **lastName** (small initial       letters)

how can I resolve this?

Comment: Apparently your JSON annotations from bean.xml didn't applied. Try to use the annotations directly in java classes.

Comment: Yah Nikolai , as part of project development process , I am trying using beans.xml

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason why you're using @JsonProperty is that the name of the parameters in your json (FirstName, LastName) are different from your java class (firstName, lastName). You should put the name of your java parameter in in the property tag, so:

```
        <property name="firstName" type="java.lang.String" >
            <annotations>@JsonProperty("FirstName")</annotations>
        </property>
        <property name="lastName" type="java.lang.String" >
            <annotations>@JsonProperty("LastName")</annotations>
        </property>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are missing `</annotations>` on the first annotations element

Comment: Oh sorry .. .actully they are present in beans.xml but I forgot to mention here in question.